# Do Conferences provide the facility of pre-submission inquiries?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, proceedings

This is my first post here, so kindly pardon any Beginner errors.

I noticed that it is common practice among authors to write pre-submission inquiries to different journals when it comes to journal publications.

I wanted to know if Conferences provide the same provision as well ?

My reason for this question is that i am working on a paper that i intend to submit to a conference whose deadline is due in just over a month's time.

I am apprehensive about submitting my paper straight away and instead would like some semblance of assurance from the conference reviewers/judges

Any help & guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated !

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify what kind of conference it is. E.g., computer science, economics, art history. Large/small etc. However, I expect that in most cases the answer is no -- the only way to get feedback is to submit.

Comment: @ThomassupportsMonica It is a Computer Science conference. It is not so big apparently, as it is just their 2nd conference.

Answer (score 1):

For some conferences the Program Chair might respond to an email enquiry. In others, perhaps not.

But there is no reason that you can't just submit your paper. If it is inappropriate in any way, you will be told as part of the review process. Don't waste people's time with something obviously off-topic, but otherwise just do it.

If a PC does respond to an enquiry it would likely be something like the above paragraph. Note that deadlines are pretty firm because of the limited time prior to the conference itself, though some conferences also extend deadlines when they don't get sufficient papers.